# Javascript Window.prototype is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

'Window' is undefined error throws if you open a simple html file where you are trying to use the Window object, from IE9. This upper case Window is used in our .NET MVC application to add custom methods to window object. This works perfect with all other browsers and even IE 11. Not sure whether its a browser specific or IIS specific issue.

```
<head>
    <script>
        alert(Window);
    </script>
</head>
<body/>
```

Comment: What code caused this error?

Comment: For testing purpose, created following simple HTML file:
<html>
<head>
<script>
alert(Window);
</script>
</head>
<body/>
</html>

Comment: What custom method did you add?

Comment: @user3467671 please post complete code here

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem without further information.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script>
alert(Window);
</script>
</head>
<body/>
</html>

Comment: It looks like some IE settings issue. Im not getting .prototype

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is caused by using uppercased variable name (`Window`). Just use `window` instead and you are all good.

Also if you just want to add a new method to window, you don't need to use prototype object. You only need prototypal inheritance when creating new objects, which is not typically the case with `window`.

So putting it together, you can just use:

```
window.onWindowFocusChanged = function (isWindowFocused) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: uppercased variable name is used to add the custom methods to window using the prototype property of javascript

Comment: Can you provide me with code on how you do that? Or can you otherwise explain me why you don't just want to use `window`?

Comment: Window.prototype.onWindowFocusChanged = function (isWindowFocused) {
    try{
        alert("Hi");
    }
    catch (err) {
    }
};